# Access an instance of a component created by Ractive Load

Tags: components, instance, ractivejs, ractive-load

Inside a component, I am happily using the syntax below to load additional components, if and when needed:

```
<!-- Import example component -->
<link rel='ractive' href='internal-example.html' name='InternalExample'>
```

My question is, how can I access this example component instance created by [Ractive Load](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive-load) inside another component?

**Important:**

I can define where the main components will be stored and I can see `...anotherMainComponent.components.InternalExample` but it doesn't appear to be a instance, since I can't use `get` or `set`

Instead it appears to be a "component definition" to be reused (which is fine to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `findComponent` method:

```js
// assuming `ractive` is the top-level instance
// (i.e. `ractive = new MyComponent(...)`)
var internalExample = ractive.findComponent( 'InternalExample' );
```

`ractive.findAllComponents` is a related method - [docs here](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive-findcomponent) and [here](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive-findallcomponents).

Comment: I am glad to see how Ractive is evolving. I am developing plugins to extend Ractive Load features to use it in production grade and large scale softwares (as the one my company is creating). Once my company permits me, I plan to create repositories and return our improvements to Ractive

Comment: looking forward to it :)